# Manwha where the female-lead was an empress and dies + goes back in time to find out a who killed her

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read a Manwha where the female-lead was the empress and died. She then goes back in time to when she was a child, and somehow convinced her family she is sick and heads to the coast for recovery so that she can investigate without interference.

I think a young knight accompanied her. In the original timeline they never got along. The knight wasn’t much of a talker, but we learned in the new timeline that he’s quite soft-hearted and dressed in a lion costume for female-lead's birthday.

Then she met the male-lead (or the second male-lead?) by the beach and found him crying. He was trying to hide his tears from her. This character has light blonde hair and maybe gold eyes. I think his parents were also of nobility, but he was an illegitimate child, so he was often neglected.

This character in the past timeline used to be the female-lead's like right-hand-man. He was known as the most handsome man, but only had eyes for the female-lead and also had a pretty infamous personality. And there were some clues that maybe he was “obsessed” with her only so that he could be closer to the crown. He seemed pretty cunning, even as a kid… and seems to find the female-lead interesting.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Comment: Someone using a different account with the same name as yours has attempted to edit this question. If that person is you, please merge your new account with the one you used to post this question by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). In doing so, you'll regain the ability to edit this question without approval from other users, leave comments within this thread, and mark an answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), if one is posted.

Comment: Do you remember how she died? Poison? Stabbing? Something else? Was she married? Was she the empress due to her birth, or due to marriage to the sovereign emperor? About how old was she when she died?